# Match multiple urls combination with regex

Tags: regex

I have a set of urls with the following structure:

```
https://www.test.com/us/page1 
https://www.test.com/us/page2 
https://www.test.com/eu/page1 
https://www.test.com/eu/page2 
https://www.test.com/fr/page1 
https://www.test.com/fr/page2
```

I'm doing as following for the regex:

```
https:/\/\www.test.com/\(us)|(eu)|(fr)|/\(page1)|(page2)
```

But it seems not matching those cases. Can anyone explain me what I'm doing wrong with a workable example?

Comment: Maybe `https://www+\.test\.com/(us|eu|fr)/(page1|page2)`? Are you sure you have 4 `w`s after `https://`? See https://regex101.com/r/vuPsso/1

Comment: It can be like `https://wwww\.test\.com/(?:us|eu|fr)|/page\d+` note that you have 4 times `wwww`

Comment: The 4 times w was a typos. But still both suggestions are not working.

Comment: @UgoL What is the tool or language? In Javascript the pattern would be `https:\/\/www\.test\.com\/(?:us|eu|fr)\/page\d+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

- [`https:\/\/www\.test\.com\/(us|eu|fr)\/(page[12])`](https://regex101.com/r/H7NS8z/3)

[image]

Note that in your question you have the escapes backwards:

`https:/\/\`

Should actually be:

`https:\/\/` (if you need to escape it, many regex flavors don't have to escape `/`)